# Script Reusability

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Need suggestions on -
I am new to selenium and implementing a POM based Robot framework. I need some suggestion on how to handle script changes in case if a functionality change that affects almost 15 scenario's.
Mostly the scripts are calling the page objects into an end to end scenario's, do we have any other approach to minimize the scripts changes?

Comment: POM is by far the famous, best, and optimal design pattern as far as I know. Can't say anything without looking at the code

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Selenium with Python, you may be able to take advantage of the Page Object Model abilities of the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) framework. Here's some code examples of that:

File 1 - `google_objects.py`:

```py
class HomePage(object):
    dialog_box = '[role="dialog"] div'
    search_box = 'input[title="Search"]'
    list_box = '[role="listbox"]'
    search_button = 'input[value="Google Search"]'
    feeling_lucky_button = """input[value="I'm Feeling Lucky"]"""

class ResultsPage(object):
    google_logo = 'img[alt="Google"]'
    images_link = "link=Images"
    search_results = "div#center_col"
```

File 2 - `google_test.py`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
from .google_objects import HomePage, ResultsPage

class GoogleTests(BaseCase):
    def test_google_dot_com(self):
        self.open("https://google.com/ncr")
        self.type(HomePage.search_box, "github")
        self.assert_element(HomePage.list_box)
        self.assert_element(HomePage.search_button)
        self.assert_element(HomePage.feeling_lucky_button)
        self.click(HomePage.search_button)
        self.assert_text("github.com", ResultsPage.search_results)
        self.assert_element(ResultsPage.images_link)
```

(Example taken from the [SeleniumBase samples/ folder](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/tree/master/examples/boilerplates/samples))

As seen above, reusable selectors/objects from File 1 are used in File 2, and could also be reused in many other files as well.

Here's a longer example, [test_page_objects.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/boilerplates/samples/test_page_objects.py), which puts methods into page objects:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class GooglePage:
    def go_to_google(self, sb):
        sb.open("https://google.com/ncr")

    def do_search(self, sb, search_term):
        sb.type('input[title="Search"]', search_term + "\n")

    def click_search_result(self, sb, content):
        sb.click('a[href*="%s"]' % content)

class SeleniumBaseGitHubPage:
    def click_seleniumbase_io_link(self, sb):
        link = '#readme article a[href*="seleniumbase.io"]'
        sb.wait_for_element_visible(link)
        sb.js_click(link)
        sb.switch_to_newest_window()

class SeleniumBaseIOPage:
    def do_search_and_click(self, sb, search_term):
        if sb.is_element_visible('[for="__search"] svg'):
            sb.click('[for="__search"] svg')
        sb.type('form[name="search"] input', search_term)
        sb.click("li.md-search-result__item h1:contains(%s)" % search_term)

class MyTests(BaseCase):
    def test_page_objects(self):
        search_term = "SeleniumBase GitHub"
        expected_text = "seleniumbase/SeleniumBase"
        GooglePage().go_to_google(self)
        GooglePage().do_search(self, search_term)
        self.assert_text(expected_text, "#search")
        GooglePage().click_search_result(self, expected_text)
        SeleniumBaseGitHubPage().click_seleniumbase_io_link(self)
        SeleniumBaseIOPage().do_search_and_click(self, "Dashboard")
        self.assert_text("Dashboard", "main h1")
```

This provides a lot of different possibilities for script reusability.